# как можно сделать систему постройки дороги?

Tags: unity3d

делаю тайкон впервые. у меня есть 7 вариантов дороги.как мне это объеденить и сделать примерно также как на картинке, но в плоском виде по клеточкам 2д.[image: картинка]

Comment: Звучит как Tile Map

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно использовать [Tilemap](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Tilemap.html) (ПКМ по окну в иерархии/2D Object/TileMap/...).
Также тебе нужно окно выбора спрайтов: Windows->2D->[Tile Palette](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap-Palette.html).
Но для начала нужны спрайты которые разбиты по плеточкам чтобы добавить их в саму палитру. Вот видео которое тебе поможет [click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-jlx2QVTuY). Также есть ассет, который будет задавать правила постройки тайлов, что значительно облегчит работу.